# Join 3 tables in Spring Jpa Data

Tags: spring, jpa, join

I've been struggling lately to join 3 tables with spring data jpa. I have 3 entities, `Series`, `Dossier` and `Item`. `Series` has many `Dossiers`, and `Dossier` has many `Items` (Relationships). I do something like `Series.join(Dossier_.series).join(Dossier_.items)` and I end up with a Join set. I want to make the following query:

```
Select Items from Series,Dossier,Item 
Where Series.Id=Dossier.seriesId 
and Dossier.id=Item.dossierId 
and series.projectId = :param
```

I can't express this statement with Spring Specifications and criteria api....Please shed some light

Comment: I have got similar requirement and same proble. what has solved your problem? can you plz reply @Rocky Savidis

Answer (score 8):

It is more a JPA question.

First, I always emphasize, you are not access "tables".  You should view them as domain entities.  Lot of misuse of JPA/Hibernate/other ORMs actually comes from direct "translate" of SQL or database concepts.

Back to your question, the answer is simple.  First make sure you actually have the "relationships" in your domain entities.  Storing IDs is not helping to build a concrete domain model.  For example, you have something like :

```
@Entity
class Series {
  @Id
  Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="series")
  List<Dossier> dossiers;
}
@Entity
class Dossier{
  @Id
  Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  Series series;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="dossier"
  List<Item> items;
}

@Entity
class Item{
  @Id
  Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  Dossier dossier;
}
```

The query is straight-forward:

```
select s.dossiers.items from Series s where s.projectId = :param
```

Or, if it is more reasonable to have only the `@ManyToOne`s and omit the `@OneToMany`s, the query is still straight-forward:

```
from Item where i.dossier.series.projectId = :param
```

Answer (score 0):

[Still rocky here] Maybe i didn't make myself clear.I know how to express the query in HQL.The problem is to use Spring Data's Specifications,with the help of the criteria api to build that query.

```
//Let's exampine the following piece of code

        public class CustomItemSpecs {

        public static Specification<Item> createSpecificationFromSearchForm(final SearchForm searchForm) {  
            return new Specification<Item>() {
                @Override  
                public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Item> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {             
        CriteriaQuery<Item> cq = cb.createQuery(Item.class);


                    CriteriaQuery<Series> sb = cb.createQuery(Series.class);
                    Root<Series> series = sb.from(Series.class);

                    Join<Series,Dossier> join1 = series.join(Series_.dossiers);

                    Join<Dossier, Item> join2 = join1.join(Dossier_.items);
        }
}

    }
```

As you can see i manage to do two seperate joins.The problem is when i want to join Series,Dossier And Items to execute the above query.Notice that join2 is a Dossier-Item set.I can't make criteria like cb.equals(join2.get(Series_.projectId),)

Answer (score 0):

im using spring data interface projection .
example like this

**note** items must be interface class

Repository Class

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Items,Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "Select Items from Series,Dossier,Item Where Series.Id=Dossier.seriesId and Dossier.id=Item.dossierId and series.projectId = :param")
    public Items findTransaksisByAccountIdOrderById(@Param("param") Long projectId);

}
```